# failed to import bean in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I am getting an exception in one of my configuration file "spring-jpa.xml".Can anyone tell me whats wrong?I have checked for similar questions but whatever i got,it didnot solve the problem.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [spring-jpa.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-jpa.xml]
```

Following is the file where i am getting the exception:

spring-jpa.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                         
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">                           

    <!-- JPA Configurations -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="letsCatchUpDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/LetsCatchUpDB"/>
        <!-- ookup-on-startup="false" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" --> 

    <!-- Used for transaction management -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Enable transactional based annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : One of its duties is to search the proper entity EntityManagerFactory that would provide the EntityManager for you @PersistenceContext annotated properties -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <!-- Used to set up Entity Manager -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <!-- org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence is deprecated.Use org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider instead.-->
        <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />     
        <property name="dataSource" ref="letsCatchUpDataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="letsCatchUpPU" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    </bean>        

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.letscatchup.repository"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
        transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>  

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you try it with the xsd url http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd? Also, which version of spring / spring-data-jpa are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying it is not able to load the `spring-jpa.xml`. Place the spring-jpa.xml in the /src folder for contextLoader to find it. Else if you are placing your spring in web inf then in `contextConfigLocation` give relative path from `/WEB-INF/..`

e.g.,

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-jpa.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

If you are placing the xml in src then - 

<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-jpa.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```